# Atribuir parametros na rota após resposta do ajax razor page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Estou criando um filtro de busca com diversas opções em ajax, ao aplicar os filtros por checkbox está filtrando corretamente, no entanto gostaria que setasse a minha url com os filtros que eu apliquei.

Exemplo, digamos que eu pesquise por audi e selecione a categoria suv, a minha url ficaria: "/filter?query=audi&category=suv".

Já tentei de tudo para que os filtros que eu apliquei seja definido na rota mas não consegui, alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -3):

Suponha que você tenha uma página Razor chamada "Filter.cshtml" e você esteja usando jQuery para fazer uma chamada de Ajax para o servidor para aplicar os filtros selecionados. Depois de obter a resposta do Ajax, você pode usar o JavaScript para atualizar a URL da rota com os parâmetros selecionados. Aqui está um exemplo de como fazer isso:

No seu arquivo "Filter.cshtml", adicione um identificador único para o seu elemento HTML que representa o botão de aplicar filtros. Por exemplo:

```
<button id="btnApplyFilters">Aplicar Filtros</button>
```

Em seu script jQuery, ouça o evento de clique no botão de aplicar filtros e faça a chamada de Ajax para o servidor para aplicar os filtros selecionados. Em seguida, atualize a URL da rota com os parâmetros selecionados usando o método pushState do JavaScript. Aqui está um exemplo:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Ouça o evento de clique no botão de aplicar filtros
    $('#btnApplyFilters').on('click', function() {
        // Faça a chamada de Ajax para o servidor para aplicar os filtros selecionados
        $.ajax({
            // Configurar as opções de chamada Ajax, incluindo a URL, tipo de requisição, dados enviados etc.
            // ...
            success: function(data) {
                // Atualizar a URL da rota com os parâmetros selecionados
                var query = 'audi'; // Valor do parâmetro query obtido dos filtros selecionados
                var category = 'suv'; // Valor do parâmetro category obtido dos filtros selecionados
                var url = '/filter?query=' + query + '&category=' + category;
                window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                // Lidar com erros, se necessário
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Essa abordagem irá atualizar a URL da rota com os parâmetros selecionados após obter a resposta do Ajax, permitindo que você defina os filtros aplicados na rota. Lembre-se de ajustar os valores dos parâmetros de acordo com os dados que você obtém dos filtros selecionados em seu aplicativo.